# Need a demo project for Visual Studio Apache Cordova with Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, visual-studio-cordova

I started to look into the Visual Studio Apache Cordova and try to build some cross platform mobile apps. I want to use Sencha Touch as the framework, but I googled a lot and couldn't find a single demo project which uses Sencha Touch, could somebody tell me where I can find one as a start point.

Answer (score 1):

You can get started by using:

Start with [Sencha Touch 2.4 Getting Started Guide][3] to and download all the resources you need locally if you haven't already.

Once you are have the environment setup, Sencha CMD will help you by generating a starting project.

There's plenty of info on that so I'm skipping ahead to the Cordova part.

```
# Make sure you are inside your app project folder

cd to/app/project/directory

sencha cordova init
```

This will add Cordova to your project.

```
# Now we will create the os level app project inside
# myapp/cordova/platforms/...

sencha app build android # or other OS
```

Assuming no errors you should have yourself a basic app you can play with.

If you want to see a very basic Sencha Touch Cordova project you can take a look at one I have, but it's a demo for iOS icon troubleshooting. You could still use it and do a build for Android or windows as there really isn't anything preventing that.

https://github.com/Trozdol/icondemo

OH! When using Sencha CMD and Cordova there are some handy commands to use if you get build errors..

```
sencha app watch # compiles SASS and Compass, creates a web server, warns of errors, etc
sencha app build
sencha app refresh

# while inside myapp/cordova/

cordova build
cordova platforms rm [os here] 
cordova platforms add [os here] # alt: sencha app build native

cordova plugin add [url to plugin repo]
cordova plugin list
```